# Margin: auto to multiple inline images

Tags: html, css, center

I'm working on this design and I'm stuck at this point. 
Here is my simplified design:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0n8wm5k/)

As you can see, I have multiple images inside a div. 
What I need to do is to make them look like this:

[image]

So they have auto margins between them and the border.

The solution for the vertical align would be to have the images at 50px height, since the `#container` div has a fixed height, or use a helper div with `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` properties, but I don't know what to do with the horizontal align, since it's not a fixed width.

I tried `display: block` and `margin: 0 auto`, but it won't work. It doesn't display the images on the same line anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: What versions of IE do you need to support? If IE8+, then you can use `display:table-cell;`

Answer (score 2):

Use `text-align:center` on the parent

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a0n8wm5k/3/)

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body, html {
    width: 100%;
}

#container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#container img{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
#container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;/*Add text align center*/
}

#container img{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;/*Add vertical align middle*/

}
#container img:not(:first-child){
    margin-left: 50px;/*Add margin not in first image though*/
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a0n8wm5k/10/)

Comment: +1 Also it's worth to note that `:not()` pseudo class is not supported in IE 8 and below.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the images inline blocks and then add `text-align: center` to the container. Then space the images out with some margins on them, like this:

```
#container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#container img{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 5%;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a0n8wm5k/2/

Comment: It is a fixed height, but I need them to center horizontally.

Comment: This does centre them horizontally. The margin only spaces them out. If you need to centre them equally without using margin for spacing then you'll need to use CSS3, which means certain versions of IE won't support it. You can use `table-cell` (as previously mentioned) or perhaps Flexbox - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Since the container is a fixed height why not give each img a padding / margin at the right?

http://jsfiddle.net/4mk6s1d5/

```
#container img{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add margin-left to the css if you need just like you have shown in the image you should increase the width of the container like

```
#container {
width: 80%;
height: 50px;
display: block;
margin: auto;
border: 1px solid blue;
line-height: 50px;
}

#container img{
margin-left:35px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
}
```

here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/a0n8wm5k/7/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 cents worth, using `table-cell`.

Note that I have added a parent container to center the `table-cell`. Your question is specific to the *images*, so I don't think that's a problem?

```
<div id="parent-container">
    <div id="container">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXxxJ8MNjZZV8-Zzwu_RfL6YnZSt8cY70fyQlgeJwg3H6dLW_m2A" />
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXxxJ8MNjZZV8-Zzwu_RfL6YnZSt8cY70fyQlgeJwg3H6dLW_m2A" />
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXxxJ8MNjZZV8-Zzwu_RfL6YnZSt8cY70fyQlgeJwg3H6dLW_m2A" />
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXxxJ8MNjZZV8-Zzwu_RfL6YnZSt8cY70fyQlgeJwg3H6dLW_m2A" />
    </div>
</div>

#parent-container {
    display: table;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}

#container img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
}
```

I have altered the height, to show that it is "fluid", regardless of the container size. This should work in IE8+, not tested though.

http://jsfiddle.net/rvfvt01a/1/